# Proving Cayley's Theorem

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Im trying to understand Cayley's Theorem.I have this proof

[image]

I have some questions

What is $Sym(G)$ - I understand that it is a permutation group? How do we get that?

How do we say if $y\in G$ then $g^{-1}y\in G$?

Comment: $\mathrm{Sym}(G)$ is the set of all permutations, that is bijections $G\rightarrow G$, together with the composition of maps.

Comment: @HagenKnaf what is composition of maps?

Comment: Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ and $g:B\rightarrow C$ be two maps. Then their composition $g\circ f$ is the map $A\rightarrow C$ defined by $(g\circ f)(a):=g(f(a))$.

Comment: @HagenKnaf okay... thanks